# How can i get all control in another page of site in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get all control in another page of my site in code behind.
For example I'm in `Default.aspx` page and I have an ASP Button.
I want, when I click on Button get list of all ASP Control in `Dashboard.aspx`
(Like `Button` , `TextBox` , `DropDownList` , etc) without opening `Dashboard.aspx` 
 
page in Browser.

Note: 
 1. Getting all Control process must be in Code Behind.
 2. I don't want open `Dashboard.aspx` page in browser.

Comment: Why don't you create a [user control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET) and place it on your page if you don't want to open it into the browser.

Comment: You think i have 50 page . I cant convert all of this page to UserControl

Comment: Sounds like you want Server.Execute(). What are you trying to do with the controls from Dashboard.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `HttpWebRequest` to solve this problem.

In `Default.aspx` page when `Clicked` on button run this code :

```
byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");

//url = "http://localhost:50036/UI/Dashboard.aspx?Action=FindControl"
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
requestStream.Flush();
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

if (httpRequest.HaveResponse == true)
{
      Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
      String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
      /*
          In responseString string i have all control and types seperated by `semicolon`(`;`)
      */
}
else
      Console.Write("no response");
```

In this code `url` Variable contain url of `Dashboard.aspx`

**Note:url must contain `http://` otherwise doesn't work**

In `Dashboard.aspx` page in `Page_Load` write this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != null && Request.QueryString["Action"].ToString() == "FindControl")
    {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ControlsList(this));
         HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}

public void ControlsList(Control parent)
    {
        string ans = "";
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox || c is Button || c is DropDownList || c is CheckBox || c is RadioButton || c is CheckBoxList || c is RadioButtonList || c is ImageButton || c is LinkButton)
            {
                if(c.ID != null && c.ID != "")
                ans +=c.ID + "," + ((System.Reflection.MemberInfo)(c.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType)).Name + ";";
            }
            ans += ControlsList(c);
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

In `Page_Load` check `Action=FindControl` then find all control with specified Type with recursive function `ControlsList` and write it to response to use in `Default.aspx`

**Its completely work for me!**